# Why is Aptana not colorizing regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, eclipse, aptana, textmate

I've been a user of Textmate for many years, but I felt in love with Aptana a few days ago and I set it up to use Textmate colors. Mostly everything gets colorized the right way except for PHP, where every string looks the same.

In Textmate, if you make an string like `$a="SELECT * from table"`, it detects you're writing an SQL query and colorizes it the right way; same works for `$a="/regex/"`, but it's not happening on Aptana.

I know it's the PHP parser because Javascript works fine: you can type `var a=/regex/` and you will get the regular expression in a different color.

I'd like to know if someone has been able to get into the parser's source code to edit it, and try to replace it with Textmate's one (which is available on the language bundle).

Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking why Aptana does not have feature X or how to port TextMate's code into Java?

Comment: I'm asking how to edit the source code of the language parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have a php library addon for aptana installed, otherwise it will not recognize it and colorize it. Then reset your colorize options. I had the same problem at first, php not being colorized, then i installed a php library, sorry i cant access the name right now, if you are still interested tomorrow i will post it, and after a restart it recognized, colorized and suggested php code correctly. Sorry for the run on sentence.

Hope that works,

Oh and i should probably note this was with aptana 2.